# React Navigation: Should I manually set higher versions for react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm using `react-native@69.10` in my React Native app, and am adding a Drawer Navigator. I have `@react-navigation/drawer@6.6.2`. The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) say to run

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

which installs `react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.3` even though the current version is 2.10.1, and `react-native-reanimated@1.13.4` even though the current version is 3.1.0.

**What I Want To Know:** These two libraries resolved to lower versions than the current available ones. Should I leave them at these versions (1.10.3 and 1.13.4), or force it to install the higher ones (2.10.1 and 3.1.0)?

Comment: If the package needs a specific version it’s specified inside the packages `package.json`. Just upgrade all of them. It shouldn’t break anything. `reanimated@v1` is the first version which is very old.